# Как загрузить из одной сборки другую сборку

Tags: c#, .net-core, assembly

Есть такой код получения типа из сборки.
Как мне загружать код через Assembly.Load() не прописывая полного пути, я когда пытаюсь так сделать прилетает ошибка следующего типа

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'TextListener, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.'

```
public static IListener CreateListenerFromAssembly(string listenerName)
{
    var assembly =
        Assembly.LoadFrom(
        $@"D:\NET02.3\{listenerName}\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\{listenerName}");
    var type = assembly.GetTypes()
        .FirstOrDefault(type => typeof(IListener).IsAssignableFrom(type) && type.IsClass);

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(type.FullName))
    { 
        throw new NullReferenceException("Can't find this listener");
    }

    var listener = assembly.CreateInstance(type.FullName);

    return (IListener) listener;
}
```

Comment: оно не может найти файл, возможно в конце пути нужно добавить `.dll`

Comment: Так Load или LoadFrom? Первое и не требует прописывания полного пути...

Comment: LoadFrom у меня работает, а вот Load выдает ошибку, хотя имя сборки все правилньо передаю

Answer (score 3):

Assembly.Load в .NET Core по умолчанию [не грузит библиотеки из каталога с программой](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/8045). Чтобы включить эту возможность нужно установить параметр Microsoft.NETCore.DotNetHostPolicy.SetAppPaths в [runtimeconfig.json](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/run-time-config/#runtimeconfigjson):

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "netcoreapp2.1",
    "framework": {
      "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
      "version": "2.1.0"
    },
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true,
      "Microsoft.NETCore.DotNetHostPolicy.SetAppPaths": true
    }
  }
}
```

Кроме того, если текущий каталог совпадает с каталогом программы, можно загрузить сборку без прописывания полного пути так:

```
Assembly.LoadFrom("Assembly.dll");
```

В общем случае, для загрузки сборки из каталога программы можно использовать вот такой код:

```
Assembly.LoadFrom(
    Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location),"Assembly.dll")
    );
```