# Динамическое подключение DLL-библиотеки

Tags: c#, dll, плагин, эксперименты

Задался задачей сделать подключающиеся DLL, по следующему принципу: в настройках (на отдельной форме) уже запущенной программы указывается путь к DLL файлу, после чего разблокируются некие возможности элементов интерфейса, с помощью которых появляется возможность вызывать заранее известные функции библиотеки.

Например у меня в программе определено описание методов/функций и класса, которые так-же будут присутствовать в DLL:

```
int GetLibraryVersion();
class SomeLibraryClass
{
   public string CurrentLibraryName;
   private int SomeLibraryClassCounter;
   public SomeLibraryClass(){}
   public void DoAction();
   public void DoActionWithParams(string param1);
   public bool CheckState();
}
SomeLibraryClass BiuldSomeLibraryClassByParams(int param1, string param2);
```

Я могу сделать DLL, которая будет уже частью программы при запуске, но не имею представления, как сделать так, чтобы уже во время работы программы можно было указать путь к нужной DLL, с заранее известными сигнатурами.
Т.е. я хочу сделать систему плагинов. Для начала пусть хоть один плагин за раз, но чтобы DLL можно было выбирать уже во время работы программы.

Как мне это сделать?

Comment: Вам нужен код примерно как в этом вопросе: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1155963/240512 В плагине тип должен реализовывать некий известный интерфейс. Вы загружаете через его Assembly.Load/LoadFrom и ищете тип с интерфейсом.

Comment: [MEF](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/mef/). [Create a .NET Core application with plugins](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/creating-app-with-plugin-support). В ранних изданиях книги CLR via C# был пример плагина; [здесь](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/449a6e3f-74ac-4239-adde-a41d2ef63365/10571086107910761072108510801077?forum=fordesktopru) его вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сторону использования LoadLibrary + GetProcAddress.
Инструкции и пример кода можно найти здесь: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jonathanswift/dynamically-calling-an-unmanaged-dll-from-net-c